# How to tell a message sent to the MPMediaPlayer has timed out?

Tags: iphone, frameworks, media-player

I've been working with the MPMediaPlayer framework for the 3.0 SDK. Sometimes the Media Player is slow to respond, or doesn't respond at all. I get warning messages in the console, but the user will never see these messages (and thus blame my app for the timeouts).

Is there a way to recover from these timeouts? Can I set things to NOT retry also?

Answer (score 0):

Does your app register to receive notifications from the MPMediaPlayer? I haven't seen these timeouts, so I don't know if they return the MPMoviePlayerContentPreloadDidFinishNotification with the userInfo filled with your error.

From MPMoviePlayerController.h:

```
MP_EXTERN NSString *const MPMoviePlayerContentPreloadDidFinishNotification; // userInfo contains NSError for @"error" key if preloading fails
```

From the MoviePlayer sample code:

```
// Register to receive a notification that the movie is now in memory and ready to play
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
                 selector:@selector(moviePreloadDidFinish:) 
                 name:MPMoviePlayerContentPreloadDidFinishNotification 
                 object:nil];

// Register to receive a notification when the movie has finished playing. 
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
                selector:@selector(moviePlayBackDidFinish:) 
                name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification 
                object:nil];

// Register to receive a notification when the movie scaling mode has changed. 
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
                selector:@selector(movieScalingModeDidChange:) 
                name:MPMoviePlayerScalingModeDidChangeNotification 
                object:nil];
```

Comment: My app does register itself for notifications, however, I'm using the MPMusicPlayer, not Movie Player. Still, seems like a worthwhile direction to look to. Thanks!